# Linking data in line chart from x and y

Tags: excel, charts, ms-office, office365, spreadsheet

Here is the issue:

X has 0 - 8

I need them to start bottom left corner, and also you see all the legends stop on same vertical line but need to be at different stop points so in theory X and Y need to have 0 - 8 and then draw the legend / items from 0,0 to the X,Y set point so if 4.54 X and Y should be 4.54.

Anyone have any ideas? I have added screenshot below.

[image]

I tried and managed to get something like this, but it's not quite right. I need to start 0,0 (bottom left) and have straight lines up until the right value by X and Y

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have also attempted a point value system which think might help. Although a point 0.00 value series I guess is required, I need to set the display like it is on the left just showing 0 - 8 and same for bottom but working on the 0.00 series basis?

[image]

[image]

Comment: To the person that requested this to be closed... really? it is a genuine question to a problem - what is wrong with that? Ive explained the problem im facing in great detail and provided in great detail as per requirements of posting a question...

Comment: Now that the CSV file has expired, I am not sure there is much value in keeping this question open (I have removed the link). Can that be re-added in a more permanent form? We discourage file lockers for exactly this reason.

Answer (score -1):

I really can't imagine what you want to achieve by this. What you want to do is basically drawing eight `y = x` lines on the SAME plane, which is visually meaningless. As far as I can tell from what you provide, your last try is right approach. You just need to edit the X-axis format. I made [something similar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mftbkdf4ux3vzm/42660276.xlsx?dl=0) based on 0.1 point system. Under this approach, I had to MANUALLY edit each series' ranges, which was also painful.

Comment: dont ask me why, trying to keep misses happy, i assume just all need to start at 0 bottom left, and each go to a end value like 7.11 both on x and y

Comment: You know how i can make it do this though? i cannot seem to work out how to change the left part as currently they are all the same and going from bottom left to top right.... plus would also be good if just shows 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 rather than those hundreds so point values lol

Comment: You can [edit](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/data-series.html) X-axis by 'Select Data...' menu or [format](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/axes.html) by 'Format Axis...' menu. It's some basic features.